# Ошибка компиляции Error:java: invalid flag: -release

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При попытке тестового запуска "Hello world", сразу ошибка:

> Error:java: invalid flag: -release

Comment: Как запускаете?

Comment: ну, обычно с кнопки запуска в самой идее